# How to turn off the default vibration of a notification

Tags: android, notifications, vibration

I am using Galaxy Nexus with Android 4.0, I set the silent mode to vibrate in Settings. I use NotificationManager.notify to send the Notification. I don't set Notification.vibrate, I even use myNotification.defaults &= ~Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE to disable the vibration. But it still vibrate after calling NotifcationManager.notify.
Could anyone tell me how to turn off the vibration of a Notification in vibrate mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the following code:

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
//or 
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
```

Answer (score 2):

To disable Vibration when notification comes, I use this code.

```
notification.vibrate = new long[] { -1 };
```

And its working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

To manage notification settings dynamically:

```
notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;

if(/*sound enabled*/)
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

if(/*vibration enabled*/)
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

First store the value of your vibrate setting button in shared preference. and then place this code where your notification is received.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = context.getSharedPreferences("VIBRATE",
            0);
boolean vibrate = preferences.getBoolean("vibrate", true);
if (vibrate) {
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be done using the following adb command for specific package

```
adb shell
cmd appops set package_name VIBRATE ignore
```

The above command will disable all vibrations for package_name package.